# How to merge text files with the same name from all subdirectories?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, merge

I have several folders with files. Files can have the same names. I want to concatenate files into one of each name. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry, can you show me the batch file for it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the windows tags, I know nothing about windows. I am pretty sure `ls` still works, possibly `cat` too but if you can do perl on then you need can do something like `ls -r A | perl -e 'system("cat $0 >> "B/" + m|/(.*)$|")'`

Comment: I don't actually use Perl so I am not sure if this exact snippet works, but the solution is definitely THAT simple and by searching for how to perform the individual actions (match regexes, do simple perl things) you can easily figure this out

Comment: Are all the folders located in the same root directory? is there any specific sort order for concatenating the files? perhaps `for /R` could be used, together with redirection `>>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

merge.bat

```
@echo off
# for every text file in
# the sub-dirs of current dir
for /r "." %%a in (*.txt) do (
   # filename without path and extension
   echo %%~na
   # read file and append it to file with 
   # the same name prefix in current dir
   type %%a >> %%~na-merged.txt
)
```

merge_all_in_one.bat

```
@echo off
for /r "." %%a in (*) do (
    type %%a >> all_merged.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple — you have go write each file to the same directory making sure you are appending. This does not guarantee any sort of order preference, so I assume it's irrelevant. You have not specified a language or whether this is for the shell, so I can't suggest an implementation (yet).

This problem can be broken down into the following tasks. First you need a list of all the files. This can be done with `ls -r` or some PL specific way, if you are "programming". Then you need to figure out for each file path, where to write and that involves a regex or probably even a split on "/". Then you just want to read and append each file from A to B and that's it. Either do that with `cat a >> b` or with whatever language libraries you are using.

Comment: This problem can be broken down into the following tasks. First you need a list of all the files. This can be done with `ls -r` or some PL specific way, if you are "programming". Then you need to figure out for each file path, where to write and that involves a regex or probably even a split on `"/"`. Then you just want to read and append each file from A to B and that's it. Either do that with `cat a >> b` or with whatever language libraries you are using.