# Windows Batch - empty files while trying to merge text files with the same name from all subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, merge

I have already found in a different topic, [How to merge text files with the same name from all subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34176797/6738015), the following code to merge the files with a batch:

```
@echo off
  for /r "." %%a in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~na
    type %%a >> %%~na-merged.txt
  )
```

In my local pc this works fine. But, when I try this on a windows server we use in a VDI, the new files are created empty. You may find below the information from cmd:

> 'ááá' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.  'áááecho' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.  'ááá' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.    Access is denied.    Error occurred while processing:
>   D:...    The system cannot find the file specified.     Error
>   occurred while processing: -.   The system cannot find the path
>   specified.   Press any key to continue . . .

Can anyone help?

Comment: Put `@echo on` and look on which line the error occurs. Also try to quote `%%a` in `type %%a ...` --> `type "%%a" ...`.

Comment: ...or even better: `"%%~a"`...

Comment: @aschipfl  It works! Thank you all for help! I had already tried with quotes but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Single line from the appropriate directory at the Command Prompt.

```dos
@(For /F "Delims=" %A In ('FindStr/SM $ "samename.txt"') Do @(Echo "%~A"&Type "%~A"))>"samename-merged.txt"
```

Change both instances of `samename` to your specific name specification.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using the "~".

```
@for /r "." %%a in (*.txt) do (echo %%~na type "%%~a" >> %%~na-merged.txt)
```

Thanks again all of you for your help!

Comment: That picks up every single `.txt` file in the scripts tree; not same name ones as stipulated in your question. What you have posted as 'worked' also does not do that which you requested in your own question!

Comment: No, it picks and appends only the files with the same name that are 
    .txt

Comment: Yes; you asked **to merge text files with the same name**, what you've posted is **to merge files with the .txt extension**. Your script as written is supposed create a duplicate file for all uniquely named text files appending -merged to their names and merge the content of any text files with the same name into a single file appending -merged to it's name. That said, and as I stated above, what you've posted as an answer certainly does not create an output file containing the merged text from the files.